# What is the "to the power of" symbol in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, symbols

For the program I am making, I need the to power of symbol, but when I try to use the general symbol (^), it doesn't recognize that?

Could anyone tell me what symbol to use instead?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3201945?start=0&tstart=0 I suspect you weren't googing using the word "exponent" as that's the first link google gives you from "objective c exponent".

Comment: It should be noted that while most math programs recognize ^ as the symbol for exponent in most programming languages (including all varieties of C, Perl, Java etc) ^ is the symbol for XOR

Answer (score 39):

there is no pow symbol.
use the C function pow(x,y);

```
double res = pow(5.0,2.0); //25
```

---

BSD Library Functions Manual

NAME:
     pow -- power function

SYNOPSIS:

```
 #include <math.h>

 double pow(double x, double y);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the "pow" function. `pow(4,3)` gives you four to the third power.